# Laravel wherehas ignored when using with

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I have a Query where I want to see all **`Alert`** (relation) items for a **`User`** for a specific type.

I'm using the following query

```
$users = User::with('alerts')->whereHas('alerts', function($q) use ($type) {
    $q->where('type', $type);
})->get();
```

The issue is it's ignoring my where `subquery` and returning the alerts for all types, not the type I'm passing into the `whereHas`.

Thank you!

Comment: whereHas limits your results of User, not your results of alerts.

Comment: Aha thanks for your answer, found solution i'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

`whereHas` limits the results of User, not the results of alerts

I had to use a `subquery` on the '`with`' statement.

```
$users = User::whereHas('email_alerts')->with(['email_alerts' => function($q) use ($email_type) {
    $q->where('email_type', $email_type);
}, 'company'])->get();
```